Gmail doesn't provide threaded view when send an email with In-Reply-To header from my CakePHP application
The trailing mechanism Gmail client (SMTP) fails to map the email trail but the Thunderbird email (IMAP) client created the trail even though the subject was different when trying sending email with custom message-ID and In-Reply-To headers.

The Message-ID format I'm using is: 'foobar' + widgetId + sequence
widgetId = a number unique to each widget e.g. 1234
sequence = a sequential number incremented each time we send an email
**First email**:

Message-ID <foobar-1234-0@server.com>
In-Reply-To: not provided
References: not provided

**Second email**:

Message-ID <foobar-1234-1@server.com>
In-Reply-To: <foobar-1234-0@server.com>
References: <foobar-1234-0@server.com>

**Third email**:

Message-ID <foobar-1234-2@server.com>
In-Reply-To: <foobar-1234-1@server.com>
References: <foobar-1234-0@server.com> <foobar-1234-1@server.com>

(incidentally, including the @server.com portion of a message ID appears to be vital. Without that, using e.g. foobar-123-0, our SMTP server simply ignored it and used its own autogenerated message ID)

Please suggest a way to do the same with the Gmail SMTP server such an email trail is formed even if the subject is changed when replied to via custom In-Reply-To headers.
